# Why does container's status is exited?

Tags: docker

I will try to briefly show the situation

```
docker run -d --name kong \
    --link kong-database:kong-database \
    --link go-server:go-server \
    -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
    -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
    -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
    -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -p 8443:8443 \
    -p 8001:8001 \
    -p 8444:8444 \
    kong:latest
```

When I inspect the container state

```
"State": {
    "Status": "exited",
    "Running": false,
    "Paused": false,
```

I tried to start it again but is is the same.

```
Port bindings
           "PortBindings": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8000"
                    }
                ],
                "8001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    }
                ],
                "8443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8443"
                    }
                ],
                "8444/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8444"
```

I tried GET request but connection was refused

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8001/status
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8001: Connection refused
```

Logs

```
docker logs -f 6bee8e8b9f5a
2019/04/25 05:10:23 [error] 1#0: init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: database needs bootstrap; run 'kong migrations bootstrap'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: database needs bootstrap; run 'kong migrations bootstrap'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
2019/04/25 05:14:40 [error] 1#0: init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: database needs bootstrap; run 'kong migrations bootstrap'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: database needs bootstrap; run 'kong migrations bootstrap'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:337: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
```

How should I change status to running mode?
SOLVED

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8001/status
{"database":{"reachable":true},"server":{"connections_writing":1,"total_requests":4,"connections_handled":4,"connections_accepted":4,"connections_reading":0,"connections_active":1,"connections_waiting":0}
```

Comment: When you are creating a container, tail the logs and post it here. `docker logs -f <container-id>`. It's will be easier to debug with the help of logs

Comment: @Thilak I can not understand logs,database has already been bootstraped.

Comment: Have you followed the [**2. Prepare your database**](https://hub.docker.com/_/kong)

Comment: I believe you can use this [**Compose file**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/docker-kong/master/compose/docker-compose.yml?_sm_au_=iVV74j6GFKPWPHJP) , which will simplify your work.